# Convert minutes into hours in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to convert 300 minutes into 5 hours.
Input is 300
Output should be 05:00

---

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(5), dateadd(MINUTE, 300, '1970-01-01'), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`
DECLARE
@FirstDate datetime,
@LastDate datetime

```
SELECT
@FirstDate = '2000-01-01 09:00:00',
@LastDate = '2000-01-01 11:30:00'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), 
DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @FirstDate, @LastDate), 0), 114)
```

`

Comment: Isn't really the question, because I only have minutes and no date.